# How to Overload Checkbox Related Functions in Android Studios

Tags: android-checkbox

```
@Override
public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
    CheckBox checkb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.a);
    if (checkb.isChecked() != checked) {
        checkb.setChecked(checked) ;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean isChecked() {
    CheckBox checkb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.a);

    return checkb.isChecked() ;
}

@Override
public void toggle() {
    CheckBox checkb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.a);
    setChecked(checkb.isChecked() ? false : true) ;
}
```

That's how one class is defined.
How do I modify those functions if I want to use them in other check boxes?
For example, you can be used on findViewByld(R.id.b);

Comment: Let me get this straight. You want to add additional methods `setChecked`/`isChecked`/`toggle` to all your checkboxes, is that right?

Comment: yes! I want to use that function in that class so that it can be used on other r.id~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two choices:

- Override `CheckBox` object (reuse methods by inheritance)
- Add `CheckBoxHelper` (reuse methods by delegation)

I suggest the second approach:

```
class CheckBoxHelper {
    public void setChecked(CheckBox c, boolean checked) {
        if (c.isChecked() != checked) {
            c.setChecked(checked) ;
        }
    }

    .. etc
}
```